# How Many Save Files Can You Have In Kid Icarus: Uprising?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I would like to know how many save files you can have in the game Kid Icarus: Uprising (3ds).

Answer (score 0):

Kid Icarus Uprising has three save slots that you can use.